# finding the year and quarter from a datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a requirement to find the completed quarter(1 to 4 from Jan to Dec), given a certain date. Note that it is not the current quarter but the completed quarter. By that I mean that if 1st Jan is the input date, then the completed quarter is 4 and not 1. The small code snippet that I have is as follows:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import math
>>> now = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> present_quarter = int(math.ceil(now.month/3.))
>>> completed_quarter = (present_quarter - 1) if present_quarter != 1 else 4
>>> completed_quarter
4
```

However what I need is the year as well so that the output is :

```
2014-4
```

What is the best way to do this ? Can the output remain a datetime object and not a string by which I mean does Python support a datetime object like **Year-Quarter**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply map the month to the quarter and a year delta (you need last year for Q4):

```
def completed_quarter(dt):
    prev_quarter_map = ((4, -1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0))
    quarter, yd = prev_quarter_map[(dt.month - 1) // 3]
    return (dt.year + yd, quarter)
```

This translates the month to a value between 0 and 3, then translates that into a quarter number and a year delta. Adding the year delta to the current year gives you the correct year for that completed previous quarter.

Demo:

```
>>> def completed_quarter(dt):
...     prev_quarter_map = ((4, -1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0))
...     quarter, yd = prev_quarter_map[(dt.month - 1) // 3]
...     return (dt.year + yd, quarter)
... 
>>> from datetime import date
>>> completed_quarter(date(2015, 1, 12))
(2014, 4)
>>> completed_quarter(date(2015, 8, 31))
(2015, 2)
>>> completed_quarter(date(2015, 12, 31))
(2015, 3)
```

The `datetime` module has no objects that can model a quarter; you can have a *date* (which has to have valid year, month and day values) or a *date and time* (adding on a valid hour, minute, second and microsecond value, with optional timezone).

Comment: @Martin..just to understand..can the final result be a date object so that I can perform standard date operation on it ?

Comment: @Amistad: not unless you translate it back to a specific date in that quarter, no. Date objects can only model an actual date, something with a year, month and day value.

Comment: @Amistad: the first day of a quarter is `date(year, ((quarter - 1) * 3) + 1, 1)` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to catch the first quarter:

```
def qrt(now):
    first_qrt = now.month < 4
    return now.year - first_qrt, (now.month - 1) // 3 if not first_qrt else 4
```

Comment: but just to understand..now.year-True = 2014 and now.year-False = 2015..what is the underlying logic for this ?

Answer (score 1):

How about extend datetime

```
class Quarter(datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Quarter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        present_quarter = int(math.ceil(self.month/3))
        self.quarter = (present_quarter-1) if present_quarter != 1 else 4
```

Using it.

```
q = Quarter(2015,1,1,0,0,0)
# Or
q = Quarter.now()
# Getting quarter
print q.quarter
```